# Is it possible to read the following txt.files using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So, I'm currently trying to make an app capable of reading a few txt files and make it available for people to see the information in it but I'm facing a problem when i try to read them.

The code seems to be working fine but it doesn't really read it, I believe it has something to do with the delimiter I used. I tried a series of delimiters but it didn't work.

This is the git repository link for my project you can find the txt files at enerlul/data. I managed to successfully read the data on painel_cont but wasn't able to do so for the rest of it.

https://github.com/lCtXl/flaskappproject

Any ideas?

This is the code I tried to use to read the file:

````
def painel_comp():
  with open('data/Espelho Painel Reincidencia_2.txt') as csv_file:
      painel_comp_dict = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep='\s+')
      return render_template('painel_comp/list.html', title='Painel Compensaçao', painel_comp=painel_comp_dict) ```
````

Comment: The link to your data is not working. Can you check it?

Comment: The file you linked gives me a 404. Also, try simplifying the problem, just check whether the file is read correctly, then what the `render_template` returns.

Comment: Link updated! try it now

Comment: The repository you are linking from seems to be a private one. You can paste the file to pastebin or use a github gist. Also, if the problem is with the template, you should provide it as well.

Comment: All set, i updated the whole thing to provide more information!

Comment: The problem most likely lies in the rendering of the template. pd.read_csv returns you a dataframe and not a dictionary, you might want to take it into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine. The file seems to be malformed though...
When a pandas dataframe is converted to a dictionary, its keys are its columns titles, in this case, they would be:

```
['10 + Ocorr�ncias Relevantes - Base Atualizada �s 12:30.',
 '              ',
 '             ',
 '             .1',
 '             .2',
 '             .3',
 '             .4',
 '             .5',
 '             .6',
 'Unnamed: 9']
```

You need to take a look at your file first, make sure its headers are matching the keys your template is trying to render

btw: sergipe rules!!! ; )

Comment: Wow dude, thank you very much i'll check it out haha

Comment: Mind if i ask how did you find out the columns titles? I'm having the same problem with another 2 files in the project, is it a tool? (by the way i managed to make it work and I'm currently reading the file! 
I'm grateful.

Comment: Your `painel_comp_dict` actually is a pandas `dataframe`, you can see its full documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html). You can see its columns with the attribute `.columns` (or you can convert it to a `dict` and get its keys)